# Optimizing a Partition Method

Tags: java

I am looking for assistance in optimizing a partition method I wrote for a class. It does its job correctly, but I only received half points on it, so I was wondering if there was a way to make it more efficient?

```
private int runPartition(int lowIndex, int highIndex)
  {
     //Sets up pivot index and values
     int pivotIndex = lowIndex;
     int pivotValue = localArray[pivotIndex];

     //Inner counter value
     int counterOne = highIndex + 1;

     //Loops through array from top down
     for (int counterTwo = highIndex; counterTwo >= lowIndex; counterTwo--)
        {
           //If element is bigger than pivot, move to end
           if (localArray[counterTwo] > pivotValue)
              {
                 //Decrements inner counter and swaps values
                 counterOne--;
                 swapValuesAtIndex(counterTwo, counterOne);
              }
        }

     //At end, swap pivot value with value BEFORE larger elements
     counterOne--;
     swapValuesAtIndex(counterOne, pivotIndex);

     //Sets new pivot index and returns
     pivotIndex = counterOne;
     return pivotIndex;
  }
```

Comment: When you say "partition method", can you specify exactly what you mean to avoid any potential confusion?

Comment: Yes - this method partitions the array around the top index in the array. For example, for an array of {3, 9, 6}, the number 6 would be the partition index, and the other items would be sorted so that the numbers equal to or less than 6 would come before it, and the numbers greater than 6 would come after it. This method is used in a quick sort method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm wondering if it is the efficiency that resulted in you getting half points:

- `runPartition` is rather an unclear name in itself;
- `highIndex` seems to be inclusive, which is uncommon (the number of elements is now `highIndex - lowIndex + 1`);
- `counterOne` and `counterTwo` are not good names for *indices* - even `i` and `j` would have been better;
- it is very likely that the `localArray` as a field name raises some questions; why is it a field in the first place? And why is it called `local` if it is not local to the method?
- it seems to me that you would set the `counterOne` to the index you want to swap and perform the decrease *afterwards* (possibly using `--` in the call to `swapValues`);
- the braces are at uncommon and uneven positions when it comes to Java / indentation.